# Eclipse Dynamic Web Module and Apache Wicket

Tags: eclipse, wicket

I want to place .html files in the same package with .java files under /src/main/java but when creating new .html file Eclipse offers /webapp as the default folder. Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: I'd recommend using Maven. Then you could simply add `<resource>` pointing to `src/main/resources/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is to offer to place it in a folder that will be deployable to the server and readable by clients.  You're still able to pick another folder, aren't you?

Comment: Yes I am. Is it so that only files under webapp folder are readably by clients? Because when the .html file was under /src/main/java the page worked without any problems.

Comment: By default, all files in the webapp folder will be accessible via URL. so anybody can view them as they are. This is good for static files like images. This is true for all java web applications, not only Wicket applications. The Wicket HTML files you put into src/main/java will *not* be accessible via a direct URL. They will only be accessible through your Wicket application.

Answer (score 0):

I like to put my Wicket HTML files in the `/src/main/resources` folder. Then I mark that folder as 'source folder' in Eclipse (Project Buildpath).
So that, I have the HTML separated from the java files, but they will be packed together (both with Eclipse and Maven).